# Help ID a WW1 Plane

Tags: military, aircraft-identification

I purchased a wooden box of glass and nitrate negatives at a flea market in Berlin Germany in 1995. There are about a dozen more in the lot with planes in them.

This image has never been published to my knowledge.

Any ideas on the plane or the pilot?

[image: Black and white photo of man standing in front of a biplane]

Comment: This image seems to be reversed left-to-right.

Comment: Yes it is, I had to choose between the emulsion side and the other - not knowing which is correct.

Comment: You can see it's reversed because of the cut of his coat: the left side always comes over the right for men.

Answer (score 29):

About the airplane: It looks like a [Fokker D.II](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fokker_D.II).

About the engine: it definitely looks like a [Oberursel_U.I](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Oberursel_U.I).

About the pilot: [thanks to @PortreeKid](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/102847/help-id-a-ww1-plane#comment288212_102849) we know him to be the test pilot Werner Emil. We speculate that he doesn't look happy since he is missing a button on his jacket

Comment: The missing button is the reason for his unhappiness :)

Comment: @U_flow  I'll update the answer 

Comment: https://fokker-history.com/en-gb/d-ii#&gid=1175965900&pid=17 Emil Werner also seems to be unhappy about a missing button.

Comment: @PortreeKid: perfectly spotted  But then this picture has actually already been published...

Comment: @sophit yes but faaaaar better quality. Presumably same series and this one is a close up

Comment: WOW - the picture I posted is an uncropped glass negative in my position.

Comment: Opps, hit enter to soon. I'm so glad I posted this, to see another broader image and a name is just mind blowing, again WOW.

Comment: Now does anyone know the photographers name?

Comment: It seems to be Emil Werner, not Werner Emil, right? (The problem being that both "Werner" and "Emil" are German first names, but of course either one could be the family name here. The answer has it the other way around than the link.)

Comment: @PortreeKid it seems to me that this is not the same series, but literally the same photo. If you overlay them in an image editor, they are identical to the last crease on the uniform, and the face doesn't move the tiniest bit. Negatives may be duplicated (and maybe flipped in process?), so it's likely that the OP got a copy.

Comment: IMil I'm just flipping back and forth in 2 windows and it does look like I have a cropped copy of the full picture. I scanned the negative I have and got a 20 meg file. I reversed (flipped) it to match the link and zoomed in on the markings on the casting of the motor and it can be clearly seen and letters can be made out but it can't be read. For a copy of a negative done probably a 100 or so years ago I don't know what to say. If you would like a zoomed in part of my picture I could work on that this weekend. I'll dig up some of the other plains in the collection and post them to.

Comment: @GregParker I'm not an expert, so a zoomed in picture will be of no use to me. What I know is that: a) negatives may be duplicated by contact printing, which almost preserves the original quality, b) glass plates used to be produced far longer than most people think (based on this thread https://www.photrio.com/forum/threads/where-to-buy-agfa-6x9-5-glass-plates.62842/ , even in the last decade). And I suppose the Berlin street sellers are not above passing copies as originals to increase price.

Comment: The box I bought has about 500 negatives of both glass and nitrate negatives in it and I bought them all for about 30 dollars, also the nitrate negatives were in a paper bag from a developer and the print is all in gothic German, I'm 100 percent certain they are not copies and period correct. Now for the print in question I don't know why they are nearly identical. I do appreciate the feed back. Thanks.

Comment: @GregParker that's interesting. But for the reason I've mentioned above, I still think that your photo and that one on Fokker museum come from the same shot. And since yours is cropped, it has to be a copy. Otherwise it would have to be physically cut from a larger original, and why would anyone do it? But it may have been copied back during WW1, to make a postcard or whatever.

Comment: I do agree with you that what I have does absolutely looks like it came from the photo from the larger shot and that it might have been for a post card, or maybe for the family of a deceased pilot?