# Which WW1 plane is this?

Tags: military, aircraft-identification

I have another scanned negative from my collection (see my [other post](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/102847/help-id-a-ww1-plane) with Emil Werner).

I just would like to know what kind of plane it is.

[image]

Comment: It sure *looks like* Werner Emil. Hard to be sure because we can't see all his buttons.

Comment: @A.I.Breveleri: note that it seems to be Emil Werner, not Werner Emil. Both "Emil" and "Werner" are German given names, but this gentleman seems to have "Werner" as his family name and "Emil" as his given name, and in German the given name comes first.

Answer (score 16):

It looks like an [Albatros B.I / B.II](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Albatros_B.II)

[image]
([source](https://www.militaer-wissen.de/albatros-b-ii/?lang=fr))

[image]
([source](https://www.militaer-wissen.de/albatros-b-ii/?lang=fr))

[image]
([source](https://i0.wp.com/www.militaer-wissen.de/wp-content/uploads/2018/02/Albatros-BII.jpg))

Comment: WOW, Nice, You guys know your stuff !!!

Comment: What a wild place to mount the radiator.

Comment: @CamilleGoudeseune I wonder if it warmed the cockpit when mounted there.

Comment: I think your photo had a lot more features that were useful than you think. That windscreen and engine are kind of unique from my experience, and I don't know as much as most on this site ;)

Comment: @Steve yeah the windscreen's main job is to divert oil from the pilot's face.

Comment: Any information about that bizarre double-decker hat? In the original photo I thought he was just being goofy and wearing two hats at once, but in your last photo here the guy in front of the prop appears to be wearing the same thing.

Comment: @CameronSS Found the answer to my own question, it's apparently called a "Roold-style" helmet and was just a way to provide extra impact/crash protection at the expense of looking goofy (and probably increasing neck strain from the wind catching it). https://historical.ha.com/itm/military-and-patriotic/wwi/rare-wwi-german-aviators-roold-style-crash-helmet/a/6098-32423.s